# PhpMyAdmin datos con URL

Tags: phpmyadmin

en Excel creo una tabla de 2 celdas y una de ellas tiene un vinculo(url) y la guardo como .csv

abro PhpMyAdmin y la importo sin problemas, pero los datos de la 2da celda salen sin el link que le asigne desde excel

-Lo que busco es crear la tabla para que se muestre en la pagina y desde la pagina poder usar el link correspondiente de cada dato

Celda1= Factura1    -   Celda2= Ver Factura

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).